# Azure Cosmos DB aggregation over nested structure

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have an azure cosmos DB with documents as below

```
{
  "id": "id_1",
  "location": "location_1",
  "colorCounts": {
    "red" : 1,
    "blue": 0,
    "yellow": 1
  }
},
{
  "id": "id_2",
  "location": "location_1",
  "colorCounts": {
    "red" : 0,
    "blue": 0,
    "yellow": 0
  }
}
```

and want make a query that groups the results by `location` while averaging all the values in `colorCounts`. My result would look like this:

```
{
  "location": "location_1",
  "colorCounts": {
    "red" : 0.5,
    "blue": 0,
    "yellow": 0.5
  }
}
```

When I try to average over `colorCounts`:

`SELECT c.id, c.location, AVG(c.colorCounts) FROM c GROUP BY c.location`

I do not get any color counts. I can average over single colors, but I do not know how to average over the nested object colorCounts.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the data model. `id` has to be unique (within a partition). Does this imply you're using the same `id` for multiple documents, across different partitions? If that's the case, you need to do cross-partition queries. But also: you can't compute `AVG(c.colorCounts)` because `colorCounts` is a nested document containing other properties. You'd need to average those individual properties.

Comment: Your second query has a syntax error (`AVG(c.colorCounts.red) colorCounts.red `) - not quite sure what this is supposed to mean, but that 2nd `colorCounts.red` shouldn't be there (plus it should be separated by a comma, even if it *was* supposed to be there)

Comment: @DavidMakogon My example data was bad, I edited the question. My problem is exactly as you said in your comment: How do I average over the individual properties in my nested property?

Comment: @user1981275 @DavidMakogan Check if below script answers the query. 

`SELECT c.location,avg(c.colorCounts.red)  as red, 
avg(c.colorCounts.blue)  as blue, 
avg(c.colorCounts.yellow)  as yellow FROM c
GROUP by c.location`

Refer this [img](https://i.imgur.com/EXwxn35.png)

Comment: @Aswin it does the averages but it does not nest it under `colorCounts` in the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Script:**

```sql
select a.location,{"red" : a.red, "blue": a.blue
 ,"yellow": a.yellow} as colorCounts FROM
(SELECT c.location,avg(c.colorCounts.red) as red,
avg(c.colorCounts.blue) as blue,
avg(c.colorCounts.yellow) as yellow FROM c
GROUP  by c.location)a
```

I tried to repro this with the same sample input and got the required output.

**Output:**

```
[
{
"location": "location_1",
"colorCounts": {
"red": 0.5,
"blue": 0,
"yellow": 0.5
}
}
]
```

[image]